# Являются ли названия букв словами?

Tags: словообразование, алфавит

Есть ли в русском языке слова:

```
"а" "бэ" "вэ" "гэ" "дэ"... "э" "ю" "я"?
```

Если это слова, то к какой части речи они относятся?

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что названия букв являются словами.

С одной стороны, это собственные существительные (индивидуальные названия предметов), пишутся с прописной буквы, например: Буква А - первая буква русского алфавита.

С другой стороны, встречаются написания со строчной буквы, например: Буквы я, ю, ё, е, и используются в русском письме в двух функциях. В этом случае это нарицательное существительное со значением вида, отнесенное к родовому названию "буква".

Таким образом, статус названия буквы зависит от контекста.

В словаре указано, что название букв является **несклоняемым** существительным ср. рода.

Comment: Нет букв Я. Буква есть. Поэтому в примере должно быть двоеточие.

Comment: Пример взят из академических правил Лопатина (цитата), поэтому все вопросы к нему.

Comment: Вы перепечатали, картинку не дали, кавычек нет.

Comment: Не надо кавычек, такую запись можно найти в любом учебнике.  Попробую Вам объяснить соотношение собственных и нарицательных существительных на примере. Официальные названия сортов растений в специальной литературе пишутся с прописной буквы и без кавычек:  клубника Виктория, тюльпан Махровый ранний (собственные имена).  В неофициальной литературе: У нас растет клубника "виктория". Цветет иван-чай (распространенное и общепринятое название цветов). Собственное имя только в первом примере, в двух других переход имени собственного в  нарицательное видовое название.

Comment: Вам удалось исказить суть цитаты. Получается, что «Буквы я используются в русском письме в двух функциях».

Answer (score 3):

Все названия букв (за искл. названий *"твёрдый знак"* и *"мягкий знак"*) -- это **имена существительные среднего рода**. Принято говорить: строчное ***о,*** прописное ***п*** и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Названия букв — имена собственные существительные. Каждая индивидуальна и не может входить в класс себе подобных, как входят нарицательные. Пишутся (с) прописной.